# React асинхронная загрузка данных в useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, асинхронность, useeffect

Пытаюсь загрузить данные через асинхронный метод в useEffect. Передаю все необходимые зависимости и в моем понимании useEffect должен отрабатывать при монтировании компонента, при первом рендере и при изменении зависимостей.

```
 useEffect(() => { 
        console.log('effect')
        if (ids.length === 0) {
            api.images.all().then((data) => { console.log(data); setIDs(data) }).catch(console.log)
        }
    }, [ids])
```

В моем случае это 3 раза: монтирование (тут же он должен загрузить данные), первый рендер (не должно войти в if), и из-за изменения ids (также не должно войти в if). Но useEffect срабатывает 4 раза и загружает данные дважды, я не могу понять почему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код компонента:

```
//BuildIn
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
//Inside
import api from '../services/api.service'
import AsyncImage from '../components/AsyncImage.component'

const ImagesPage = () => {
    const [ids, setIDs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => { 
        console.log('effect')
        if (ids.length === 0) {
            api.images.all().then((data) => { console.log(data); setIDs(data) }).catch(console.log)
        }
    }, [ids])

    return(
        <>
            {(ids.length > 0) ? ids.map((id, index) => <AsyncImage guid={id} key={index} />) : <div>No data</div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default ImagesPage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая причина почему так происходит.

#### Ваш компонент используется в нескольких местах.

Это довольно логично, если компонент в нескольких местах, то соответственно
эффект будет вызываться из-за переиспользования компонента. И запрос будет отправляться каждый раз.

---

Вторая причина.

#### Что-то наверху в дереве компонентов обновляется.

Очень вероятно что один или несколько родителей обновляются. Или просто монтируются и размонтируются тоже может вызвать перерисовку этого компонента в дереве потомков. Надо просто по всем родительским компонентам пройтись и посмотреть что вызывает ререндер.

---

Третья причина.

#### Включен строгий режим реакта  [(React.StrictMode)](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Я лично склоняюсь к третьей причине. Скорее всего у вас просто стоит строгий режим. Так как вы работаете в режиме разработки.

Приведу пример:

```
App.js

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todos.length === 0) {
      console.log("Внутри");
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => setTodos(response))
        .then(() => console.log("последний then"));
    }
    console.log("эффект", todos);
  }, [todos]);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

---

```
index.js

import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Обычный компонент. Со строгим режимом будет два раза заходить в блок if

```
if (todos.length === 0) {
```

Да, именно. Если включен `StrictMode` он ДВА раза будет заходить и дважды отправит запрос. Можно проверить [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-moon-8g18my?file=/src/App.js:69-522).

Это примерно такая же логика как у вас. Если уберете `StrictMode`, то все будет работать как вы ожидали.

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы были правы, включен StrictMode

Comment: @РоманМатвеев всегда рад помочь :)